# tar: extract a member reliably with possible leading dot-slash

Tags: tar

Let’s say I have two tar archives generated in slightly different way:

```
$ tar tvf archive1.tar 
-rw-r--r-- root/root 567 2016-09-18 14:28 member1
-rw-r--r-- root/root 1696 2016-09-18 14:28 member2
$ tar tvf archive2.tar 
-rw-r--r-- root/root 567 2016-09-18 14:28 ./member1
-rw-r--r-- root/root 1696 2016-09-18 14:28 ./member2
```

How to extract member1 **reliably** from either of two archives? I’m receiving the tar over a pipe, the generator isn’t under my control, and while I can run the pipeline multiple times, I’d really like to avoid doing so without necessity.

P.S.:

```
$ tar xOvf archive1.tar member1 > /dev/null
member1
$ tar xOvf archive2.tar member1 > /dev/null
tar: member1: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Comment: BSD tar, apparently, doesn't have the problem: it worked for me both ways. When I needed a GNU tar format, I ended up mentioning both `member1` and `./member1`. It exists with an error code, but does the extraction; so I have no guarantee extraction worked.
Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, I did not; in fact, I haven’t touched that code since that day :D

Comment: What I was trying to do was write a script which would dump the contents of `.deb` and `.ipk` of all existing subformats without requiring `dpkg-deb`. There is such a script part of MC, but it only supports standard-compliant `.deb` files and requires dpkg. Many `.ipk` files do not follow the standard in multiple ways (e.g. using tar instead of ar, packing members in a different order, not providing `debian-binary`), which makes that script fail.

Comment: Unfortunately, it turned out, the root of the archive is another thing lots of packages (and also `ar` and `tar`) cannot agree on: many on them come with `./`, while others don’t have this prefix.

Comment: Probably writing such things in shell is a bad idea anyway.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the command line switch  `--no-anchored` may do what you want. From the [tar(1) man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tar) (they really are very useful to read or a least scan)

> **--no-anchored**
>   patterns match after any '/' (default for exclusion)

```
tar -tvf test
-rw-rw-r-- iain/iain         0 2016-09-18 16:14 ./member1
-rw-rw-r-- iain/iain         0 2016-09-18 16:14 ./member2
```

Then

```
tar -xvf test  member1
tar: member1: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

And then

```
tar -xvf test --no-anchored member1
./member1
```

Comment: I thought about this, but this will work only when the archive is guaranteed to not have `member1` anywhere else in the hierarchy, which covers only one of the two cases I have.

And sure, obviously I have studied the manpage before posting the question :)

Comment: You did not state that member1 could appear anywhere in the path or multiple times.

Comment: It's at least worth mentioning that a solution will work for MCVE, but not in a general case.

Answer (score 1):

I've been in the same boat. tar is so bafflingly underdocumented for a de-facto standard utility! Most of us [do not have Dan around](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC112), so unfortunately...

My use case involves tar archives, some of which produced by software out of my control, and the task at hand is extract the top-level directory named either './opt/' or 'opt/'. This is part of an automated VM imaging process, that I obviously want to work robustly.

What I came up with is far from a general solution, but does the thing I need, in my limited scope. It won't generalize well if you need to extract a large number of top-level directories, and dealing with cases where the names of the top-level directories are not known in advance is tricky.

GNU tar has a `--transform=` option that takes a sed `s` operator, but unfortunately, command-line pattern match is performed before the transform is applied. However, building upon @user9517's answer which I gladly upvote, I came up with the following <s>elegant solution</s> horrible hack that does the job anyway. The idea is to both match `opt/` anywhere in path and use the transform to redirect files that happen to spuriously match `opt/` anywhere except the top level into a temporary path with a transform, to be deleted after extracting. The full command is like this:

```
tar xvf $tarfile --no-anchored \
                 --transform='s:^\(\./\)\?[^o][^p][^t]/:.deleteme/&:' \
                 --show-transformed-names \
        opt/
```

The sed-like transform breaks down like

```
^              only at the path start
\(\./\)\?      match ./ if present
[^o][^p][^t]   followed by any three characters that do not make "opt"
/              followed by /
```

The `&` in the substitution part stands for the original path, to avoid any possible clashes. The `v` and `--show-transformed-names` are only for logging the extracted names.

---

POC. Note the directory `sys/opt/` that is spurious and unwanted. The cwd was cleaned before each extraction.

A tar packaged with the `./` prefix:

```
kkm@buba:~/.tmp/tarext$ tar tvf ../tar.withdot.tar
drwxr-xr-x kkm/kkm           0 2020-01-07 21:26 ./
drwxr-xr-x kkm/kkm           0 2020-01-07 21:26 ./dev/
-rw-r--r-- kkm/kkm         100 2020-01-07 19:09 ./dev/file1.dev
-rw-r--r-- kkm/kkm         100 2020-01-07 19:09 ./dev/file2.dev
-rw-r--r-- kkm/kkm         100 2020-01-07 19:09 ./dev/file3.dev
drwxr-xr-x kkm/kkm           0 2020-01-07 21:29 ./opt/
-rw-r--r-- kkm/kkm         100 2020-01-07 19:09 ./opt/file1.opt
-rw-r--r-- kkm/kkm         100 2020-01-07 19:09 ./opt/file2.opt
-rw-r--r-- kkm/kkm         100 2020-01-07 19:09 ./opt/file3.opt
drwxr-xr-x kkm/kkm           0 2020-01-07 21:26 ./sys/
-rw-r--r-- kkm/kkm         100 2020-01-07 19:09 ./sys/file1.sys
-rw-r--r-- kkm/kkm         100 2020-01-07 19:09 ./sys/file2.sys
-rw-r--r-- kkm/kkm         100 2020-01-07 19:09 ./sys/file3.sys
drwxr-xr-x kkm/kkm           0 2020-01-07 21:26 ./sys/opt/
-rw-r--r-- kkm/kkm         100 2020-01-07 20:45 ./sys/opt/file1.opt
-rw-r--r-- kkm/kkm         100 2020-01-07 20:45 ./sys/opt/file2.opt
-rw-r--r-- kkm/kkm         100 2020-01-07 20:45 ./sys/opt/file3.opt
kkm@buba:~/.tmp/tarext$ tar xvf ../tar.withdot.tar --no-anchored --transform='s:^\(\./\)\?[^o][^p][^t]/:.deleteme/&:' --show-transformed-names opt/
./opt/
./opt/file1.opt
./opt/file2.opt
./opt/file3.opt
.deleteme/sys/opt/
.deleteme/sys/opt/file1.opt
.deleteme/sys/opt/file2.opt
.deleteme/sys/opt/file3.opt
kkm@buba:~/.tmp/tarext$ rm -rf .deleteme/ ; ls -RA
.:
opt

./opt:
file1.opt  file2.opt  file3.opt
```

A tar packaged without a prefix:

```
kkm@buba:~/.tmp/tarext$ tar tvf ../tar.nodot.tar
drwxr-xr-x kkm/kkm           0 2020-01-07 21:26 dev/
-rw-r--r-- kkm/kkm         100 2020-01-07 19:09 dev/file1.dev
-rw-r--r-- kkm/kkm         100 2020-01-07 19:09 dev/file2.dev
-rw-r--r-- kkm/kkm         100 2020-01-07 19:09 dev/file3.dev
drwxr-xr-x kkm/kkm           0 2020-01-07 21:29 opt/
-rw-r--r-- kkm/kkm         100 2020-01-07 19:09 opt/file1.opt
-rw-r--r-- kkm/kkm         100 2020-01-07 19:09 opt/file2.opt
-rw-r--r-- kkm/kkm         100 2020-01-07 19:09 opt/file3.opt
drwxr-xr-x kkm/kkm           0 2020-01-07 21:26 sys/
-rw-r--r-- kkm/kkm         100 2020-01-07 19:09 sys/file1.sys
-rw-r--r-- kkm/kkm         100 2020-01-07 19:09 sys/file2.sys
-rw-r--r-- kkm/kkm         100 2020-01-07 19:09 sys/file3.sys
drwxr-xr-x kkm/kkm           0 2020-01-07 21:26 sys/opt/
-rw-r--r-- kkm/kkm         100 2020-01-07 20:45 sys/opt/file1.opt
-rw-r--r-- kkm/kkm         100 2020-01-07 20:45 sys/opt/file2.opt
-rw-r--r-- kkm/kkm         100 2020-01-07 20:45 sys/opt/file3.opt
kkm@buba:~/.tmp/tarext$ tar xvf ../tar.nodot.tar --no-anchored --transform='s:^\(\./\)\?[^o][^p][^t]/:.deleteme/&:' --show-transformed-names opt/
opt/
opt/file1.opt
opt/file2.opt
opt/file3.opt
.deleteme/sys/opt/
.deleteme/sys/opt/file1.opt
.deleteme/sys/opt/file2.opt
.deleteme/sys/opt/file3.opt
kkm@buba:~/.tmp/tarext$ rm -rf .deleteme/ ; ls -RA
.:
opt

./opt:
file1.opt  file2.opt  file3.opt
```